# Real Analysis: Prove that metrics are not comparable on $\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Prove that metrics $d_1(x,y)=\left | x \right |+\left |y  \right |$ for $ x\neq y$ and $ d_2(x,y)=\left | x+1 \right |+\left |y+1  \right |$ for $x\neq y $ are not comparable on $\mathbb{R}$.

Find a set $A \subset \mathbb{X}$ that is open with respect to the metric $d_1$ but is not open with respect to the metric $d_2$.

Find $B \in G_2\backslash G_1  $.

For the first parts, I find such a ball open with respect to $d_1$ but not open to $d_2$ for an open subset A such that $(-1,1)$.
But for finding $B$ is in $G_2\backslash G_1 $, I couldn't do this part.

Can you help me?
In there $G_2,G_1$ show that the $G_{\delta}$ for ${\delta}$ is 2 and 1, collection of open sets.

Comment: Are they metrics at all? I dont think so. d(x,x)!=0 if x!=0

Comment: For $x \neq y$ yes they are metrics

Comment: But it does not work like that. They are not metrics, because metrics is two argument function on some set X and You can take x=y.

Comment: @MaciejFicek is right. Metrics must be defined on the entire space of tuples of the underlying space.

Comment: @MaciejFicek $d(x,x) = 0$ always, so it is not unheard of to define a metric for $x \ne y$ and leave the obvious value implied. Now you may be concerned that $d$ is not continuous (with respect to the usual topology) at $(0,0)$. But such continuity is not a condition of being a metric. As long that they are symmetric and satisfy the triangle inequality (which they do), they are metrics.

Comment: Just noticed I inadvertently left off the condition of being positive definite. But these are positive definite as well, so they are still metrics.

Comment: yes they are metric, they are called post office metric

Answer (score 1):

Note that for any $y \ne x, d_2(x,y) \ge 2$. What do you get when you take a ball of radius $< 2$ about $x$?

Note for $y\ne x, d_1(x,y) \ge |x|$. What happens when take a ball of radius $< |x|$ about $x$?

Where do you see a difference in those two situations?